# Thymeleaf dialect inside a Thymeleaf dialect

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to use a Thymeleaf dialect inside a Thymeleaf dialect but couldn't. I've tried this but didn't work as well:

```
<h2 th:text="|${response.name} has: |">
Dunie has: 
    <span th:text="|-${response.size}-|" class="paleo">-4-</span>
</h2>
```

`th:text` of `h2` removes everything inside it.  I want to get something like that after rendering:

```
<h2>
Philie has: 
    <span class="paleo">-3-</span>
</h2>
```

So, how can I do what I aim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **th:block** http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag

```
<h2>
    <th:block th:text="|${response.name} has: |" />
    <span th:text="|-${response.size}-|" class="paleo"></span>
</h2>
```